# How to debug a website on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, debugging, remote-debugging

How do you debug iOS websites?
I have a website, which is behaving wrong on the iPhone compared to Firefox/Chrome on desktop. To figure out whats going on, I need to debug it.

Is there something like the developer tools in Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: I searched for this topic, but the things I found were old, outdated.

Answer (score 1):

If you view the site from your laptop, there should be an icon on the inspector tools at the top, that looks like a phone and iPad/tablet:

[image]

if you click on it, you can choose the device (iPhone 5 for example) and it will simulate an iPhone 5 viewing the page.

[image]

P.S. To get clicks to work, you may need to click the finger pointer at the top of the simulation:

[image]

Comment: This simulates iPhone resolution not the functionality of iOS itself.

Comment: Yes, but it still shows a website from mobile view, and from the OP's question it seems like mobile website functionality that needs to be debugged rather than iOS specific problems.